# Insert random values from a List into Spark's dataframe's column

Tags: java, apache-spark

I would like to insert some random values into a dataset column for testing purposes.

```
List<String> randValues = Arrays.asList("bla","foo","bar","yo")
Random rand = java.util.Random();
df.withColumn("testColumn", randValues.get(rand.nextInt(list.size())));
```

I thought this would work, but only one value is actually picked by the list, and that one will be assigned as value for the entire column.
A UDF is also not an option because the UDF receives as argument the name of another column to collect the values from, while my values come from a list and not from a column.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Example in scala but it could be achieved in java, I used `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`. I mapped array `String` values to `Column` using `lit` function and then converted them to spark's array thanks to `array` function (that function expect varargs `def array(cols: Column*): Column` so I used `:_*` to pass each array element as a single argument). In the next step I extracted array element using `element_at` and `rand()` function.

```
val df = spark.range(10)
val arr = Array("bla","foo","bar","yo")
df.withColumn("x", element_at(array(arr.map(lit(_)):_*),lit(ceil(rand()*arr.size)).cast("int"))).show
```

output:

```
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  0|bar|
|  1|foo|
|  2|bar|
|  3|foo|
|  4|bla|
|  5|bla|
|  6|foo|
|  7|bla|
|  8|bla|
|  9|foo|
+---+---+
```